# Could not open input file app/console

Tags: php, symfony

I installed wamp server and a copy of the Symfony2 framework. I am trying to create a Bundle, using the following command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --nampespace=IDP/IDP_Bundle --format=yml
```

My PHP is in `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10`

But when I run the command it says:

```
could  not open input file app/console
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you in the project directory?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Dont run the command from the php path.

Add php into your path environment variable

and then cd to the project

```
C:/wamp/www/yourproject
```

and then run the command

```
php app/console generate:bundle --nampespace=IDP/IDP_Bundle --format=yml
```

It will work

Answer (score 44):

To execute command you should move to root directory of your project in terminal/CMD.

Please note that in `version 2.5` some changes has been made so command will not work with `app/console`

**Note:** From 2.5 `app/console` is replaced by `bin/console`.

Please check [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md) for changes. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994473/631652) for more details about difference.

Comment: Given recent changes, this should now be the answer.

Answer (score 9):

For newer versions of Symfony (2.4.x or newer) use this method on windows to resolve the problem:

1. Go to project directory e.g. d:/xampp/symfony2-project/ and open composer.json and place this under requires array `"symfony/console": "2.4.*@dev"`. And save the file.
2. Open command-line and cd to project's directory.
3. Use this command to let download and install the dependencies: `php path/to/composer.phar install`. Remember you should be in your project's directory and path/to/composer.phar is the actual path to your composer.phar file.
4. Now you are all done, just use `php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=Test/PrintBundle --format=yml`

Answer (score 3):

Actually You need to be in your project root to run this command and you have to add php directory to your system env path variable.

1. Add your php directory to the system path variable
2. cd to the root of your project

Answer (score 3):

I'm use Symfony 3 and the Bundle calendar-bundle.
This error is present in the documentation of: Bundle: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

The form correct is:

```
php bin/console assets:install web
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

First check the Environment Variable which is in Advanced system setting -> set path of `C:/wamp/www/bin/php` and then

run cmd->go to the directory of your project which is in www folder using cd `C:/wamp/www/yourproject`

use then user `php app/console` that shows the all command.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you (i.e., your user) don't have access to read/execute `console`.  I've never worked with with file permissions on a WAMP stack so I'm not sure what you'll need to do to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that you have the line :

```
//umask(0000);
```

in your `/web` file, `app_dev.php`.

If after doing :

```
php app/console generate:bundle --nampespace=IDP/IDP_Bundle --format=yml
```

in your project path, you still can not generate your bundle, try uncommenting the unmask line. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when installing the pear library

my issue was, when downloading the **go-pear.phar file, it downloads as the (.txt) extension** which i didn't see.

jst change the file extension to .phar and run the code